# CKEDITOR : Find Text and Put Span tag around the Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I am wondering if there is any way to find text in CKEDITOR Programmatically

and put a **SPAN** tag on the Particular Text.

My Content is like this

```
<p>This is my co<b>nte</b>nt</p>
```

My Vision is To find a **content** text and put a span Around it.

If I'm going to use CKEDITOR dom walker it cannot Find the **Content** Text in the Editor.

Please, anyone give me the solution to that Problem.

Thank's in advance.

[image: Answer from CKEDITOR]

Comment: where is your code , what have you tried so far.?

Comment: I tried this place [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/5my9w/ ) link.But i'm not constructing the full thing.

Comment: And I also am trying the below thing now [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996938/how-to-search-a-word-through-coding-in-ckeditor-using-javascript]

Comment: just posted an answer see if that helps you out.

Comment: do mark the answer if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

`CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.window.getFrame().$` retrieves a native DOM element for editor editable area. 
So:

```
$( CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.window.getFrame().$ ).contents().find( yourelement);
```

Or if you want to find a specific text then

`$( CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.window.getFrame().$ ).contents().find( 'span:conatins("your-text")')`

Should solve your problem.

Also note that CKEditor provides an API for DOM manipulation:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.document.getById( 'elementID' );
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.document.getElementsByTag( 'div' );
```

for more documentation read this section 
[documentation CKEDITOR.instances](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR-property-instances)

Comment: But,i need to find the Text inside the Element

Comment: there is a `:contains` selector you can use with jquery, see here https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/ , for example `$( CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.window.getFrame().$ ).contents().find( 'span:conatins("your-text")');`

Comment: Ok ,i will try and i also posted that image that you needed now.Please refer this.I am trying your code in console.

Comment: I'm trying the above thing but it gives the below Error.                  
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: conatins
    at Function.Sizzle.error (jquery-3.2.1.js:1580)
    at PSEUDO (jquery-3.2.1.js:1927).Do you want the screen shot for this.

Comment: we are almost there do you have a live link that i could see ?

Comment: Kk ,wait a minute i will create a link for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158745/discussion-between-mari-selvan-and-muhammad-omer-aslam).